# Whats the reason websites rewrite external URLs to redirect through a local service?

Tags: seo

If you post anything on Twitter, the URL will be displayed as a regular URL, but it will actually take user through an internal service that redirects to the final URL.

Example:

`https://twitter.com/kuizinas/status/865622481834344449`

This tweet mentions the following URL `http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-display-contents`. However, the user is taken to `https://t.co/L9Grdm1qEu` which then redirects to the final URL.

The same is being done by Facebook and most other major web portals.

Whats the reason?

Comment: You can gather metrics directly when the links go to your own domain, not so easily when they link externally.

Comment: This is a URL shortner. This is done to share more easily and perhaps for other similar reasons.

Comment: Questions here are required to be about [websites under your own control](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 3):

Its for security reasons, they can run it through a database of virused/dangerous urls and if it then shortens it, it can then  either warn you, or block the redirect. Many sites do this things, as I said: for security. Google does it for the "Visit Page" on an image and for certiant websites. Obviously Twitter does this as well, a lot of the times the shortened url is shorter than the starting url so if someone wants to copy it it is much shorter..

Also as someone said recently "it is for metric tracking" see where Twitter is being redirected to the most, they also send some analytics to the sites

Comment: The security argument is questionable – you can just remove the content that mentions the URL in the first place.

Comment: security for the site that the link is on is questionable but for the client clicking the URL it is not, it could also be called privacy, protection and such.